# Symfony - findOneOrFail returns array message

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony4

In my Symfony service I wanted to add small edit so I decided it's better to do it inside the class.

In my controller I am getting **storyId** (it's not table ID, it's a string with different chars) from my Request like:

```
 $story = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
 $storyId = $story['storyId'];

 $freeStoryName = $this->storyRepo->findOneOrFail(['storyId' => $storyId]);
 $story->freeStoryName($freeStoryName);

 return $this->json(["message" => "SUCCESS"]);
```

And In my Entity class I handle it like:

```
public function freeStoryName(Story $story): Story
{
    $this->setPreviousStoryName($story->getStoryName());
    $story->setStoryName(null);
}
```

And I get the error message:

> Call to a member function freeStoryName() on array

I know what the message means but do not get it? It's `findOne()` method..
And other question will be, do I need `flush()` method in the Entity class like I had in a service?

Comment: Where does the `findOneOrFail` method come from? I may have missed it but it does not look as part of the standard Symfony or Doctrine code.

Comment: It's on AbstractRepository. It contains FindOneBy() method in it, so it shoud be all good. :) I tried FindOneBy as well, same thing. @FrancescoAbeni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using freeStoryName on `$story` which is an array (`json_decode($request->getContent(), true);`)

You need to use your method with your result :

```
 $story = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
 $storyId = $story['storyId'];

 $freeStoryName = $this->storyRepo->findOneOrFail(['storyId' => $storyId]);
 $freeStoryName->freeStoryName($freeStoryName);

 return $this->json(["message" => "SUCCESS"]);
```

If you feel that it's a little weird to do it this way, you could change your method to:

```
public function freeStoryName()
{
    $this->setPreviousStoryName($this->getStoryName());
    $this->setStoryName(null);
}
```

And use it:

```
$freeStoryName->freeStoryName();
```